# Uploading Set<String> gives error in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Okay, so I'm creating chips tiles that are stored in a Set, but when I try to upload it to firebase I get this error "Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of '_CompactLinkedHashSet'"

I isolated the code and simplified it so it looks like this:

...

```
Set<String> _tags = <String>{};
_tags.add('Test1');

Firestore.instance
    .collection('tags')
    .document(tagsID)
    .setData({
  'tags': _tags,
});
```

...

I've tried debugging it, and I can't get it to upload so is there any other kind of way I can get the data from the set and upload it to Firebase? Another data type I can use that Firebase will accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [data types that Firestore supports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Sets are not supported. You could convert your set to a JSON string, or to a list:

```
List<String> tagsList = List<String>.from(_tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Bryson Thill's answer, if you need to use Sets in your code, I'd recommend you use the `toList()` method before uploading to Firestore.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you following the answer from this question: 
[Adding an Object to Cloud Firestore using Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170298/adding-an-object-to-cloud-firestore-using-flutter)

And you can basically upload any data you want